# Get highest row for specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Mountain High Mountain_range
Mont Blanc  4810    Harz
Zumsteinsoitze  4563    Apeniny
Signal Kuppe    4554    Sudety
Dom 4545    Apeniny
Liskam  4527    Apeniny
Weisshorn   4506    Apeniny
Matterhorn  4478    Apeniny
Gross Glockner  3790    Alpy
Corno Grande    2912    Sudety
Rysy    2499    Pireneje
```

Thats the result im currently getting with my query

```
SELECT g.mountain, g.high, p.mountain_range from dbo.mountain as g JOIN dbo.mountain_ranges as p ON g.id_mountain_range = p.id_mountain_range ORDER by g.high DESC;
```

My task is to get only highest mountain for each mountain_range.
How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for lateral join, which in SQL Server use the `APPLY` keyword:

```
SELECT m.mountain, m.high, mr.mountain_range 
FROM dbo.mountain_ranges mr OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) m.*
      FROM dbo.mountain m 
      WHERE m.id_mountain_range = mr.id_mountain_range
      ORDER by m.high DESC
     ) m
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have SQL server 2005+ version.

```
;
WITH cteHighestRange AS ( 
SELECT g.mountain,
g.high,
p.mountain_range,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY p.mountain_range ORDER BY g.high DESC) AS  RowNum
FROM dbo.mountain as g
INNER JOIN dbo.mountain_ranges as p ON g.id_mountain_range =  p.id_mountain_range
)
SELECT mountain,high,mountain_range
FROM cteHighestRange
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```